Laravel RouteNotFoundException for route 'login' in custom middleware
I'm encountering an issue with Laravel where I'm getting a RouteNotFoundException for the route 'login' within a custom middleware.
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
}

And here's the error message I'm receiving:

Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route
[login] not defined.

I've verified that the 'login' route is defined in my routes files, and I've tried clearing the route cache, but the issue persists. Can someone please help me understand why this error occurs and how I can resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Can you share your routes file? Also share the output of the php artisan route:list command

Check your route. You should have a GET route with name Login. ->name('login'). If it is not exists, simply add it to your route.
